# What's the point of CommonJS or ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript

This sounds really stupid to me, but I don't really have an answer for this.

What's the point of using ES6 modules or CommonJS (in browsers using browserifiy), if you can just connect multiple js files to the html via the script tag so they act as modules (sharing the same scope)?

Comment: Multiple JS files using HTML tags is not the same as modules. I suggest reading some articles about modules in JavaScript, like [the Eloquent JavaScript article on modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#ch_modules), [SitePoint's article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/) or any of the top results when searching for "es6 modules".

Comment: For people reading this in 2022: You should prefer ES6 modules, since CommonJS is more specific to Node.js-related _old_ packages. With syntax-level ES6 modules import, better static-optimization like tree-shaking is one of the advantages against CommonJS(CJS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In decent sized web applications, you have to take in count that more than one developer is working on the project, so separation of concerns is one of the key elements to develop a maintainable application, lets pains the next fake scenario:

You have a file within your web application called library.js. 
ES2015 module syntax

```
    export function calculatesquareArea(object) {
        // code that calculates area
    }
    export function calculateVolume(object){
        // code that calculates volume
    }
```

And now we import this module into our code by doing something like this:

```
import { calculatesquareArea } from 'library'
// We log the output of the execution of calculatesquareArea
console.log( calculateSquareArea(object))
```

You can notice right away that in my module I have 2 functions but I've decided to only import one because at that time I've only needed to use that. Maybe this is a silly example but you can picture code reuse with the modularity nature of CommonJS or ES6 modules.

There is a more elaborate article on the key differences between CommonJS and ES2015 modules [here](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e)

Hope this helped a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I get it.
But me and a friend of mine were just working on not that big of a app, and him not being familiar with all the tech that lets you work with modules(babel, browserify) and he suggested to just use multiple script tags for moduling.
Our program is not that big, so we could avoid using bindings from scripts, that are loaded after a certain one, and have a strict sequence of files.
So I thought for a second, that it might been a reasonable solution in our case

Comment: I totally get your point, but it's better to have good practices in your everyday coding, it will flow naturally later. Always try to have a balance between readability and moderately verbose code.